# How to use Google's Closure to compile JavaScript

Tags: javascript, minify, google-closure, google-closure-compiler

Google just released [Closure](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/), which is a compiler to minify JavaScript.

On the product site, it says "The Closure Compiler has also been integrated with Page Speed".

How do I use Page Speed to compile my web pages JavaScript with Closure?

(Or, is there a web site that I can simply paste in my JavaScript to have closure minify it?

Comment: Google is great because they typically provide walkthroughs and tutorials of their "developer" software. Closure is no exception. Start [here](http://code.google.com/closure/) and follow the links to the tool that you want to learn about. Then, just read and follow along. They have a ton of information about each tool. Enjoy!

Comment: hey @Ted, I'd expand the question to include "how to compile javascript" on a command line also.

Answer (score 10):

For a single file it's simple

```
java -jar $path_to_jar/compiler.jar --js input_file.js \
          --js_output_file output_file.js
```

For a multi-file project you can use [`calcdeps.py`](http://code.google.com/closure/library/docs/calcdeps.html) in combination with the [`compiler.jar`](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/gettingstarted_app.html)

```
#!/bin/sh$
$CALCDEPS_PATH=/path/to_calcdeps  #directory containing calcdeps.py
$JAR_PATH=/path/to_jar            #directory containing compiler.jar
$CLOSURE_PATH=/path/to_closure    #contains directory "closure"
$CALCDEPS_PATH/calcdeps.py --path $CLOSURE_PATH \
                           --path . \
                           --compiler_jar $JAR_PATH/compiler.jar \
                           --input main_project_file.js \
                           --output_mode compiled \
                           > compiled_project_file.js
```

That way compiler gives meaningful information about type errors, etc. Type errors can be caught at compile time because `compiler.jar` uses [certain `JSDoc` comments](http://code.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler.html) for type information.

Extra compiler flags can be passed to `calcdeps.py` along with `-f` or `--compiler_flags` options

If you want to use advanced optimizations set

`--compiler_flags "--compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS"`

notice the double quotes and the equal sign - had to use that format in bash

Answer (score 1):

The Closure compiler is now available as a JavaScript application. No need for the Java dependency anymore

There are a few ways to integrate with it. I have done it as part of Rollup

ex:

```
import rollup from 'rollup';
import closure from 'rollup-plugin-closure-compiler-js';

export default {
  entry: 'index.js',
  dest: 'dist/build.js',
  format: 'iife',
  plugins: [
    closure({
      languageIn: 'ECMASCRIPT6',
      languageOut: 'ECMASCRIPT5',
      compilationLevel: 'ADVANCED',
      warningLevel: 'VERBOSE',
      externs: [{src:`
                      var jQuery;
                      jQuery.fadeIn = function() {};  

                      var ko;  
                      ko.applyBindings = function(vm) {};
                      ko.computed = function(a,b) {};
                      ko.observable = function(a) {};
               `}],
    })
  ]
}
```

More info here:

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/using-the-closure-compiler---advanced_optimizations

Answer (score 0):

"Page Speed 1.4 Beta integrates the Closure Compiler to minify JavaScript files automatically. However, you will need to download and install the Page Speed Beta and Closure Compiler separately."

http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/download.html

I haven't installed this version yet, but I'm fairly certain that Page Speed will present you with compiled code in its optimization recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Closure Compiler is integrated with Page Speed [only for Windows](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:code.google.com/speed/page-speed/download.html+"closure+compiler"+"page+speed").

Answer (score 0):

Use the closure compiler with PHP (hosted via CURL or local via command line tool)

http://bohuco.net/blog/2009/11/google-closure-compiler-with-php/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to compile multiple js files or if you would like to simplify compilation process, you may use kjscompiler: https://github.com/knyga/kjscompiler (based on google closure compiler)