# Closure Compiler combine files

Tags: javascript, phpstorm, google-closure-compiler

I have the following setup in my phpstorm, and I would like to combine my javascript files located in the `/js/app` and `/js/lib` folder.

now it's only minifying a single jar, I would like to combine them

[image]

Comment: try this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691969/how-to-use-googles-closure-to-compile-javascript

Answer (score 4):

One simple way to do it:

1. Create a closure.command file (or whatever you want to name it) in the same directory as your js files. Put Closure command line options in it like so:

> --js file1.js
>
> --js file2.js
>
> --js_output_file all.min.js

2. Edit the Closure file watcher arguments to include "--flagfile closure.command".  You will probably want to uncheck the "Create output file from stdout" option.

** Since you want it to operate on js files from different directories you may have to modify the file paths and "Working Directory" option for it to work properly.